# Instance methos not found when using logos %new

Tags: ios, logos, cydia-substrate

I'm using logos to make a tweet. I use %new to add a new method `- (void)checkTQT` to SBAwayController, but when I invoke the method using `[self checkTQT]`, it says "instance method '-checkTQT' not found(return type defaults to 'id')"

here is my code:

```
%hook SBAwayController
- (void)lock
{
    %orig;
    [self checkTQT];
}

%new(v@:)
- (void)checkTQT
{
    ...
}
%end
```

Do I use it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `checkTQT` or put it before your `lock`

Declare it like this:

```
- (void)checkTQT;
```

Or adjust the sequence:

```
%hook SBAwayController
%new(v@:)
- (void)checkTQT
{
    ...
}

- (void)lock
{
    %orig;
    [self checkTQT];
}

%end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that gives me a big hint. Simply put `%new` before `- (void)lock` doesn't work, so I write a catagory `@interface SBAwayController()
- (void)checkTQT;
@end` and that solves the problem